# FB.ui feed not giving a callback

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, fbjs, fb.ui

I am unable to get any feedback from my Facebook FB.UI() method. I am convinced that I am using it correctly, as the actual post does post to my wall, but the callback data is either missing or empty. I am using:

```
                    FB.ui({
                       method: 'feed',
                        name: 'asd',
                        link: 'asd',
                        picture: '',
                        description: 'asd'
                    }, function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                            if(response.post_id) {
                               $.post("ajax/wall.php",{wall : 1});
                            } else {

                            }
                        }
                    );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure how this resolved itself, **but it did** :)

I cleared my cache and changed my code to below and it worked (however I don't believe the change of code actually played any influence on it:

```
FB.ui({method: 'feed',name: '',link: '',picture: '',description: 'asd'}, function(data) {
    console.log(response);
    if(data && data.post_id) {
        $.post("ajax/wall.php",{wall : 1});
    } else {
        alert("not sent");  
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem and have never been able to get a response from Facebook for the callback function. I don't see anything in console.log or any alerts I insert in the function.

My solution was to put a URL in FB.ui's redirect_uri that goes to an HTML page with self.close (or window.close). The FB.ui popup redirects there after the user's input and immediately closes. Remember to change your FB app's Site URL setting so it matches the domain the file resides on.

Here's my code, tied to my form's submit action. The function(response) callback is still there but not used. If anyone sees a syntax error please comment on it.

```
    FB.ui ({
        method: 'feed',
        name: '',
        link: '',
        picture: '',
        caption: '',
        description: '',
        actions: {name:'',link:''},
        redirect_uri: 'http://.../self.close.html'
        },
        function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            if (response && response.post_id) {
                alert('yes');
                self.close();
            } else {
                alert('else yes');
            }
        });
```

The line of code in self.close.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">self.close();</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `redirect_uri` item and the call back will be fired.

I was facing the same issue a few mins back and realized that removing the `redirect_uri` solved it.

Comment: His sample doesn't contain a redirect_uri

Comment: "Neutral-voting" - I have this problem, and am not using the `redirect_uri` either.  Of course, that doesn't mean that this couldn't solve the problem for *some* people, just not me (nor the OP).  So, no downvote nor upvote... Just a neutral-vote with a comment. :) (very tempted to downvote, though!  Perhaps you can update your answer to be a bit more relevant?)

Answer (score 2):

For any who encounter this problem later, I had the exact same issue and fixed it like so:

```
<div class="post-view-backdrop hide" id='post-view-backdrop'>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
```

became

```
<div class="post-view-backdrop hide" id='post-view-backdrop'></div>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

The post-view-backdrop div was never meant to contain the fb-root, I just missed a close tag.

The problem was improperly formed HTML around my fb-root. I only found this on a hunch, definitely reason to use an html validator.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone on Phonegap tackling this issue -- the problem is with the fb connect plugin. It simply doesn't fire the callbacks.

Here's a code snippet from FacebookConnectPlugin.m:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// FBDialogDelegate

/**
 * Called when the dialog succeeds and is about to be dismissed.
 */
- (void)dialogDidComplete:(FBDialog *)dialog
{
    // TODO
}

/**
 * Called when the dialog succeeds with a returning url.
 */
- (void)dialogCompleteWithUrl:(NSURL *)url
{
    // TODO 
}

/**
 * Called when the dialog get canceled by the user.
 */
- (void)dialogDidNotCompleteWithUrl:(NSURL *)url
{
    // TODO 
}

/**
 * Called when the dialog is cancelled and is about to be dismissed.
 */
- (void)dialogDidNotComplete:(FBDialog *)dialog
{
    // TODO 
}
```

I'm not an Objective C programmer so I'm not trying to solve this, probably have to wait till the plugin is complete...

Answer (score 1):

setting a redirect_uri disables the callback