# After FB.ui feed popup don't close after send post

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

How close FB.ui feed dialog after send post. After click send i see white popup. How fix this problem? Also in Chorme Browser console i see https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter/inP_iYjVh9g.js?version=41 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

Comment: is it a page or canvas app? any test link?

Answer (score 0):

For the FB.ui share dialog I've achieved this with a little help from jQuery:

```
$('#fb_dialog_loader_close').trigger('click');
```

I had to do it this way because the dialog didn't close when an error was returned.

Obviously that only works if the dialog is injected into the DOM, but you could try to use `self.close` as well as fallback.